# Keypress event on group of controls in a form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, background-color, keypress

I Set the controls back ground color in Red when i press the submit button without any data in mandatory fields. But i need to re enter data in these missing mandatory fields. When i start to re enter data, the back ground red color goes white. Is there any chance to change all other mandatory fields color to White?

```
Private Sub TXTEMPID_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TXTEMPID.KeyPress
    UncheckMyControls()
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 8 Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UncheckMyControls()
    Dim txt, cmb, mtxt, rtxt As Control
    For Each cmb In EMPGBDATA.Controls
        If TypeOf cmb Is ComboBox Then
            If cmb.BackColor = Color.Red Then
                cmb.BackColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each rtxt In EMPGBDATA.Controls
        If TypeOf rtxt Is RichTextBox Then
            If rtxt.BackColor = Color.Red Then
                rtxt.BackColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each mtxt In EMPGBDATA.Controls
        If TypeOf mtxt Is MaskedTextBox Then
            If mtxt.BackColor = Color.Red Then
                mtxt.BackColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each txt In EMPGBDATA.Controls
        If TypeOf txt Is TextBox Then
            If txt.BackColor = Color.Red Then
                txt.BackColor = Color.White
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This is my Code

Comment: Can you show us your code to understand better the concept and the problem?

Comment: @HaBouF -- My code is given below...

Comment: I cannot see it. Please add the code in the question section.

Comment: @HaBouF -- Can u check now??

Comment: @Thanzeem : Just a suggestion, you could simplify your code a lot. Since `BackColor` is a property of the base `Control` class, you could simply iterate over your controls and set their `BackColor` property to Red or White, accordingly, regardless of their actual type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SolarBear suggested:

```
     For Each cnt In EMPGBDATA.Controls
        If cnt.BackColor = Color.Red Then
            cnt.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
      Next
```

Now can you describe your problem exactly?

So after your comments:
You said that you are able to check if the mandatory fields are blank and if yes you are setting their backcolor to red. and you popUp as message.
After the message you want in the first time that the user try to type something in any of your textboxes to reset the color to white:

```
   Private Sub txt_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress,TextBox2.KeyPress,TextBox3.KeyPress,TextBox4.KeyPress
 'After the Handles you put all the textboxes,richtexboxes that you want
 'THis way you handle the same event for a lot of controls in the same Sub
     UncheckMyControls()
   End Sub
```

So after your comments2:

```
    Private Sub control_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress,TextBox2.KeyPress,TextBox3.KeyPress,ComboBox1.KeyPress,ComboBox2.KeyPress
 'After the Handles you put all the textboxes,richtexboxes,comboboxes that you want
 'THis way you handle the same event for a lot of controls in the same Sub
     UncheckMyControls()
   End Sub
```

Comment: But again i miss some fields to enter. it shows red color while i am pressing the submit button. i again start entering data not working. I mean it only work in TXTEMPID_KeyPress event.. What is the solution???

Comment: I don't get exactly the problem. Maybe you can be more clear on that. Explain what you want to achieve (example I have  3 textboxes, 2 comboboxes and  when I press the submit button I need to check if these controls are having values...something like that)

Comment: Why you are putting this code in TXTEMPID_KeyPress event. Wh not in btnSubmit.Click event?

Comment: Sorry, My English is not OK. I'll explain. I have an Employee data form with text boxes, combo boxes, masked text boxes and rich text boxes etc. When i press the submit button without any data in mandatory fields it shows an error and the fields show in red color. i want to enter data in the red colored fields again, all the red colored fields go to white. i give code for change red color to white in TXTEMPID key press event. My problem is data in TXTEMPID and not in another text box, this code is not working, only work with TXTEMPID key press event. Clear HaBouF???

Comment: Not totally clear but let me try to help you.
I prefer the TextChanged event. I notice  KeyPress is working (in my case at least but I need to press one additional time a key). So I will add some code in my main answer

Comment: So where else you tried the code and it didn't worked ?(You said is working only with XTEMPID key press event)

Comment: Under TXTEMPID key press event, i use UncheckMyControls() function. Like this i should use every text boxes key press event and combobox mouse click event. Its become a long code..

Comment: Yea... it works fine.. But it is along code... For each and every controls key press event, i should call UncheckMyControls(). Actually i want a simple code. That is why i ask you friend. If no chance leave it...

Comment: I provide a code that you can handle all the keyPress events in one sub.Is not a long code, since you write one sub event. So it is not for each and every control's keyPress event.

Comment: You can add also after the Handles your comboboxes. See new code

Comment: I believe that you are using wrong events. I would use TextChanged for textBoxes and SelectedIndexChanged for comboboxes. But know I believe you got the concept